# android menu transparent color

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, menu, background-color

I made an Navigation-Drawer on the left and a menu on the right but my menu on the right (3 dots menu) is over the blue line...

I had the same problem with my Title text-view but i simply made his background-color transparent to fix it. Sadly i haven't been able to do the same with my menu.
Is there a way to make my menu background transparent or a work around to make my blue line go over it?

Here is how i made my menu:

MainActivity

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_view, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Menu options
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.map_view:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map view pressed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //startActivity(GoogleMapsActivity.class);
        return true;


    case R.id.infrastucture_only:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Infrastucture only pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.infrastucture_map:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Infrastucture + map pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.camera_only:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera only pressed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.camera_infrastucture:

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Infrastucture + Camera pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //startActivity(MetaioActivity.class);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

menu_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
android:id="@+id/dots_menu"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
android:showAsAction="always"
android:title="@string/dots_menu">
<menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_map"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/map"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/infrastucture_only"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/infrastucture_only"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/infrastucture_map"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/infrastucture_map"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/camera_only"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/camera_only"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/camera_infrastucture"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:title="@string/camera_infrastucture"/>
      </menu>
   </item>

  </menu>
```

Thank you :)

I fixed the problem. I forgot to go to my style.xml file and add the transparency to my custom style like this:

```
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
<item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Now i don't know why when i open the menu it's not transparent
http://i821.photobucket.com/albums/zz140/miguel_melo_43/openWindow_zpse164f5b7.png

Is there a better way to make the menu so i can customize like i did with my navigation drawer?
http://i821.photobucket.com/albums/zz140/miguel_melo_43/NavDrawer_zpscaf04f64.png